# How to call Neo4j database api in R Studio

Tags: r, neo4j

Please I created a Neo4j database instance, and I am trying to call it in R Studio, using the neo4r and neo4jshell packages. After running the api call, I still get a `404`even though I correctly specified the url, username, and password. Please find my code below:

```
library(neo4r)
library(neo4jshell)

myTwitter <- neo4j_api$new(
  
  url = "http://54.152.83.7:7474",
  user = "neo4j", 
  password = "mypassword"
)


myTwitter$ping()
```

When I run the last line of code, I get the `404` instead of `200`, which obviously means my api call was not successful. Please I would appreciate your helpful suggestions. Thank you

Comment: if you use a command line utility such as `curl` with the same credentials and URI, does it work?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then, it's not an R issue, is it?

Comment: I am not sure at this point

Answer (score 3):

HTTP endpoints were changed since version 4 of Neo4J

- Neo4j v3 had endpoint `http://localhost:7474/db/data`
- Neo4j v4 uses `http://localhost:7474/db/{databaseName}/tx` instead of it.

Seems like Neo4j library for R needs to be updated...

I'm not familiar with R but you could try to use available HTTP client for R that supports Basic authentication to send `POST` requests to Neo4J API with JSON payload. I also see you use `http` schema which means your credentials will be sent as plain text through the network, which is not good.

Payload for such requests should be in form of:

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "MATCH(n) RETURN n"
    }
  ]
}
```

*(adjust Cypher query to your needs)*
Response will be JSON object with `data` section containing actual results.